# Minimum Stable Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I need to compile a minimum Linux kernel, I mean, 
with the basic and generic modules to get it work on low resources machines.

Is there any specification of the minimum modules that a kernel must have to accomplish my needs?

The unique requirement is that it must be stable.

Where can I find information about it?

Comment: It's a little dated, but http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~okeefe/p2b/buildMin/buildMin.html seems to be aimed at your desires.

Comment: 1) 'Stable' is not a unique requirement 2) "acomplish my needs" means we must know what your needs include; ex: do you need an MMU? 3) The smallest Linux kernel I heard about was ~50kB.

Comment: Thanks Amber, but that article does'nt say nothing relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what "accomplish my needs" means, but whenever I need something real small/quick/easy I use: http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/